# Modified Bessel function ratios

Tags: matlab, fortran, bessel-functions

How can I handle BesselI(0,a)/BesselI(0,b) to prevent NaN in Fortran or MATLAB?

I expect a method of simplifying the ratio or a mathematical trick to handle the problem. I try a series representation of BesselI(0) but sometimes, it fails to converge.

Comment: By Bessel(0,a)/Bessel(0,b) do you mean J0(a)/J0(b) in which case you are dead in the water if J0(b) evaluates to exactly zero unless J0(a) is also zero. Otherwise it is a real pole in that mathematical expression. Cases where a simplification is possible have a sensible limit eg. as x->0 for sinc(x) = sin(x)/x but would explode if calculated naively. In that case you can substitute the analytical limit of 1 for the case of x=0.

Comment: @MartinBrown Given the title and what might be an I at the end of the function name I suspect it is I0(a)/I0(b) that is required, if so life is more sane. But we really need that to be clarified **by editing the question, not as a comment** and at the very least the values of a and b that are causing problems - but really we need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] to see how this site is used and also reading [ask] to see what kind of answers are expected here. If you have a programming question, I agree with Ian Bush that you should show that code that is giving you the problem. An example, Fortran or MATLAB, just one of them. If you have a mathematical on, Stack Exchange has other site for that.

Comment: `BesselI(0,a)/(BesselI(0,b)+0.0000000000000001)` ?

Comment: `Besseli(0,a)` is never zero.